# TypeError: duplicate base class object

Tags: python

Class 1:

`class Class1(object, object):`

Class 2:

`class Class2(object)`

`from <directory>.<filename> import Class`

Run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
i = Class2(somestring)
p = Class1(string1, string2)
```

Then I get the Error!

Comment: what error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should use `__init__(self, item1, item2)` if you want to use `Class1(string1, string2)`. Using `class Class1(object, object):` doesn't mean that you can later use `Class1(string1, string2)`

Comment: This error isn't that shocking; a function definition and a function call both put parameters/arguments in the same place. I've read a critique of the `class` statement that points out this exact discrepancy.

Comment: @furas I have that inside the class

Comment: using `class  Class(object, object)` you try to inherit your class from class `object` two times which is weird. And errors show it.

Comment: Don't edit the question to ask something entirely different. Your original syntactic error has been resolved. If you have a different problem, you need to ask that in a new question.

Comment: > class Class1(object, object):
the very objective programming

Answer (score 0):

Base classes are different from constructor/initializer arguments. Both classes should simply inherit from `object` (though in Python 3 you don't need to do so explicitly. The place for one or more arguments is in the definition of `__init__` (or `__new__`, but we'll keep this simple):

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, str1):
        ...

class Class2:
    def __init__(self, str1, str2):
        ...
```

If you do specify additional base classes, they must be *unique*.

```
# Illegal
class Class1(object, object):
    ...

# Legal, even though str also inherits from obj
# Don't actually do this, though.
class Class1(str, object):
   ...

# Legal: preferred version of the above
class Class1(str):
    ...
```

Comment: I get this error now: TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, str

Comment: @johnrao07 you should add this error in question when you was writing it.

Comment: @furas when I replace the 2nd argument object with str, I get this error. The error in the question is with the code provided

Comment: @johnrao07 change order `class Class1(str, object):` and it will work. Base class should be as last. Somewhere in documentation it is described.

Comment: My bad, answer is fixed. Don't actually list two base classes when you know one inherits (directly or indirectly) from the other, though.

Comment: I get this error now. TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: What are you actually doing? (Don't answer that; it's a rhetorical question.) I'm not saying every class should i inherit from `str`; it's just an example of the inheritance *syntax*.

Comment: I get it now, I am deleting it